# How to define magnetic pressure in a 5 dimensionnal spacetime?

Tags: special-relativity, magnetic-fields, spacetime, pressure, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

In the usual 3+1 spacetime, it is well known that the magnetic field has pressure $p_{\perp} = \rho$ (perpendicular to the field line) and tension $p_{\parallel} = -\, \rho$ (along a field line), where $\rho = \tfrac{1}{2} \, B^2$ is the field energy density (I'm using $c = 1$).  These pressure components are the eigenvalues (with a change of sign!) of the energy-momentum tensor (2) shown below.

Now, consider a 4 + 1 ($D = 5$) Minkowski spacetime, with a magnetic field only:
\begin{equation}
F_{ab} =
\begin{pmatrix}\tag{1}
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0
\\
0 & 0 & B_{12} & B_{13} & B_{14}
\\
0 & - B_{12} & 0 & B_{23} & B_{24}
\\
0 & - B_{13} & - B_{23} & 0 & B_{34}
\\
0 & - B_{14} & - B_{24} & - B_{34} & 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{equation}
The magnetic field has 6 independant components so it cannot be represented as a vector (or a pseudo-vector) in 4d space.  The field energy-momentum has the following components (I'm using metric signature $\eta = (1, -1, -1, -1, -1)$)
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
T_{ab} = F_{ac} \, F^c_{\;\, b} + \frac{1}{4} \, \eta_{ab} \, F_{cd} \, F^{cd}.
\end{equation}
This tensor doesn't have a nil trace: $T^a_{\;\, a} = \frac{1}{4} \, F_{ab} \, F^{ab} \ne 0$.

How should we define the magnetic field pressure components, in the case of (1)?  Would the pressure and tension components be the *eigenvalues* of the space part $T_{ij}$ of (2)?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the problem is - aren't the spatial components $T^{ii}$ of stress-energy always the pressure, regardless of where that $T$ is coming from?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, in 3+1 spacetime, the magnetic pressures aren't given directly by $T_{ij}$.  You need to contract $T_{ij}$ to certain directions in space (the local field line direction, or in the perpendicular plane), to get $p_{\parallel}$ and $p_{\perp}$.  In 4+1 spacetime, the field isn't a vector (it's not even clear it's a surface!), so it's not obvious to me how to get the main pressure components.

Comment: Maybe I should get the eigenvalues of $T_{ij}$?  I've edited the question.